# Can't get word wrap to work in an iframe text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxmaf/509/)**

I've added jQueryUI resizable to the editor but I'm having trouble getting wordwrap to work.Can anyone show me how to use `word-wrap: break-word;` so that it'll wrap the text  when there are no spaces between words.

I've tried `#textEditor {word-wrap: break-word;}` or `#textEditor body {word-wrap: break-word;}` but none of them works.

```
<a id="bold" class="font-bold">B</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="italic" class="italic">I</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id="fonts">
 <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
 <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
 <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
 <option value="Monotype Corsiva">Monotype</option>
 <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
 <option value="Times">Times</option>
 </select>
<br/>
<div id="iframewrapper">
 <iframe id="textEditor"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#textEditor {word-wrap: break-word;}

.ui-resizable-helper { border: 1px dotted gray; }

.iframewrapper { display: block; width: 100px; height: 400px; padding: 30px; border: 2px solid gray; overflow: hidden; position: relative;word-wrap: break-word; }


.font-bold
{
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.italic
{
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
     font-style:italic;  
}
.selected
{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

jQuery Script:

```
$("#iframewrapper").resizable({
    alsoResize : '#textEditor'
});



$(document).ready(function(){
       document.getElementById('textEditor').contentWindow.  document.designMode="on";
     document.getElementById('textEditor').contentWindow.  document.close();
    $("#bold").click(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    }else
    {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
        boldIt();
    });
    $("#italic").click(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    }else
    {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }ItalicIt();
    });
    $("#fonts").change(function(){
    changeFont($("#fonts").val());
    });

});

function boldIt()
    {  
       var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
       edit.focus(); 
       edit.document.execCommand("bold", false, ""); 
       edit.focus();
    }

function ItalicIt()
     {  
        var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
        edit.focus(); 
        edit.document.execCommand("italic", false, ""); 
        edit.focus();
     }

function changeFont(font)
{
    var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
        edit.focus(); 
        edit.document.execCommand("FontName", false, font); 
        edit.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`break-work` is a property that splits a word if its containert element's width is smaller than text size.

Your container in this case is not the `#textEditor` iframe element, but the body generated inside it. So the `word-wrap: break-word` property must be set in the body element, inside the iframe.

Since it's generated, you can set it via javascript, adding `$('#textEditor').contents().find('body').css("word-wrap", "break-word");` to your document ready method.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kxmaf/514/

Answer (score 0):

most easy way: when calling designMode = "on" also call document.body.style.overflowWrap = "break-word". On Css you can declare word-wrap: break-word so there is no need to call it in js. Only the body inside the iframe will need to be manipulated with overflowWrap...do not use overflow-wrap...his semantic is not valid on js...use overflowWrap.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please capitalize abbreviations such as JS and CSS. You can format code using backticks `` ` `` to make your answer easier to read. Thanks in advance :-)